# Is Office required to install the Microsoft Office 2010 Primary Interop Assemblies?

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office

Is it mandatory to have Microsoft office pre-installed before we try to install Microsoft Office 2010: Primary Interop Assemblies Redistributable ? As i am not able to install the PIAs without office being installed and the documentation on https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=3508 however has no mention of it in requirements.

Comment: I don't think Office is required. Otherwise, you'd be unable to install the prerequisites for a .NET application with *optional* Office support. But I don't have references to back it up.

Comment: As I recall it is required, yes, and should even be the same version. Certainly, no program can execute with the PIAs, alone. This is why there are no redistributables for later versions of Office. If you need these for the dev environment they should be part of the Visual Studio version that was concurrent with Office 2010 (VS 2010). You can also use VS to generate a set of IAs that you can distribute with your software.

Answer (score 0):

The installer checks indeed whether the respective Office component is present.

If you are on .NET 4 or later you are able to embed the interop code into your assemblies (set *Embed Interop types* to true in the properties of the respective assembly reference). That way you can avoid the whole issue of having to deploy the PIAs.